# Using bash to extract sentences that contain different tenses of a specific verb

Tags: regex, bash

I want to extract sentences from a book that contain a list of verbs and their different tenses.

For example, for the word `embellish`, I want my program not only be able to recognize `embellish`, but also `embellishing`, `embellishes` and `embellished`. Here's what I did in `bash`:

```
word="embelish"
echo "It was embellished ..." | grep -E "${word}""ed"
```

This could easily recognize the sentence `It was embellished ...`. I want to use alternatives in bash like below command to recognize different tenses:

```
echo "It was embellished ..." | grep -E '"${word}""ed"|"${word}""es"'
```

However the command failed to recognize the sentence. I tried different combinations of alternatives without any success.

Could you suggest as how to use alternatives in the regular expression, so that I could detect the different tenses in one command?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to remove all double quotes from the grep argument and then replace the single by double quotes. That's because variables are not expanded withing single quotes. In fact, everything between single quotes is taken literally.

Comment: May I ask, why not just `grep embellish`? This will find the tenses as well.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Thank you Stefan. Your solution worked. The reason why I did not use this is for some shorter words, they might be part of a bigger word `(effect > sideeffect)`. Also there are verbs that are not a simple adding of a few characters for its different tenses. It seems to me to better specify based on the last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all double quotes from the grep argument and then replace the single by double quotes. That's because variables are not expanded withing single quotes. In fact, everything between single quotes is taken literally. Thus when you write

```
echo "It was embellished ..." | grep -E '"${word}""ed"|"${word}""es"'
```

You are searching for the literal string

```
"${word}""ed"|"${word}""es"
```

If, instead, you write

```
echo "It was embellished ..." | grep -E "${word}ed|${word}es"
```

the variable `word` is expanded and you are searching for either `embellished` or `embellishes`.

By the way: You can save some typing by grouping the ending `ed`, `es`, etc together.

```
echo "It was embellished ..." | grep -E "$word(ed|es|ing)"
```